# Can the two curve $x=a$, $y^2 + x=b$ form a coordinate system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves, coordinate-systems, curvilinear-coordinates

I'm interested in constructing a curvilinear coordinate system with coordinate axes being these two curves:
$$x=a, \qquad y^2+x=b,$$
where $a, b$ are parameters that specify the families of the curve, and points on this coordinate can be described by $(a,b)$. Is that something possible? Given two curves, what are some conditions such that they can form a coordinate system?

Comment: Is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (a,b)$ bijective?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Is bijectivity between $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ the only condition required to form a curvilinear coordinate system in $(a,b)$?

Comment: This follows from the first sentence in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system). Most (if not all) coordinate systems we use are however nicer, namely, differentiable. This is not a problem in your case. Is your system a coordinate system? If not on what subset of $\mathbb R^2$ it is one?

Comment: The map is bijective on the upper half of the coordinate plane $\{(x,y)|x\in \mathbf{R}, y\geq 0\}$, so it seems like they form a coordinate system in that space. However, I also heard that the integral curves of two vector fields form a coordinate system iff their Lie bracket vanishes. In this case, the above two curves are the integral curves of the two vector fields $v_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, v_2=-2y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $, and their Lie bracket do not vanish. It seems to suggest that they cannot form a coordinate system?

Comment: I have never heard that the integral curves of two vector fields form a coordinate system *iff* their Lie bracket vanishes.

Comment: It seems I found the [reason](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810299/can-the-two-curve-x-a-y2-x-b-form-a-coordinate-system?noredirect=1#comment10233406_4810299) for this confusion and made a few comments there.

Comment: @KurtG. - FYI, your link refers back to this same thread. I assume it was supposed to point to a different thread?

Comment: @PaulSinclair . Thanks ! I meant [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4807798/949989).